# Select back things that don't exist

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table.  I want to select back the items that don't exist already, so I can create them.

```
table tags
+---------+-------+
| tagId   | name  |
|   1     | C     |
|   2     | DX    |
|   3     | CG    |
```

Say SQL looks like:

```
select name from tags where name in ( 'C', 'CG', 'RX' )
```

You get back `'C'` and `'CG'`, so you know you have to create `'RX'`.

Is there a way to get a MySQL statement like this to return `'RX'` instead, when `'RX'` doesn't already exist?

Comment: Are the items like 'RX' found in any other table, or do you just have some external list of items to check for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets assume your tags ('c', 'cg','rx') are in a table called tags_match with the same structure as above

then you could do this:

```
select tr.name 
from tags as tl 
    right join tags_match as tr 
    on tl.name = tr.name
where tl.name is null
```

This will find all the items in tags_match that are not in tags, so this would give you the desired result, but unfortunately your tags ('c', 'cg','rx') are not in a table :(

No matter we can use a subquery to 'fake' the table

```
select tr.name 
from tags as tl 
    right join (select 'cg' as name 
                union select 'c' as name 
                union select 'rx' as name) as tr 
    on tl.name = tr.name
where tl.name is null
```

Although its a little ugly, this will work.  If you have lots of items you want to test you may want to consider creating a real temporary table.

Comment: +1 Very nice - I forgot about using UNION to create the rows and was focused on the 'names' existing in another table.

Answer (score 1):

*Sure!*

```
select name from tags where name not in ( 'C', 'CG', 'RX' )
```

*Only problem is, that if the `not in` list is long, this query will be slow because it'll have to check each element against each row's `'name'` field in order to determine if it's not in the list, as opposed to an `in` where, when it matches, it'll stop checking the list at that point and return the row.*

---

**Edit:** The above solution is wrong. I am very sorry. The real solution is below.

Here is how you do it in one line of SQL:

```
select name from (
    select "C" as name
    union select "CG"
    union select "RX"
) as foo
where name not in (select name from tags);
```

Comment: This will return rows with names not in the list.  The poster appears to want to return a new set of rows with names in the list that aren't already in the table.