# MySQL Query that return "not exists value"

Tags: mysql

I want to know is it possible to do if I have 4 number as below

**1,2,3,4**

In my data base have data exists as below

**1,2,3,5,6,7**

How can I query database and return **4** in 1 query

Please advise

Comment: Erm, `SELECT 4 FROM [TableName]`?!

Comment: This might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886797/select-back-things-that-dont-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO example VALUES (1),(2),(3),(5),(6),(7);

SELECT t2.id FROM example AS t1
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS id UNION
  SELECT 2 AS id UNION
  SELECT 3 AS id UNION
  SELECT 4 AS id
) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  4 |
+----+
```

Or use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (4);

SELECT t2.id FROM example AS t1
RIGHT JOIN tmp AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

To see what's happening, switch things around a bit:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM example AS t1
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS id UNION
  SELECT 2 AS id UNION
  SELECT 3 AS id UNION
  SELECT 4 AS id
) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;

+------+----+
| id   | id |
+------+----+
|    1 |  1 |
|    2 |  2 |
|    3 |  3 |
| NULL |  4 |
+------+----+
```

Comment: Did I need to create the table every time I want to use this query?

Comment: The `example` table?  No, that's just to give you an idea of how it works.  The `example` table is just a replacement for your real table.

Comment: Thank you again Mike for your nice explaination

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM
  ( SELECT 1 AS id UNION
    SELECT 2 UNION
    SELECT 3 UNION
    SELECT 4
  ) AS TBL1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM thetable)
```